# jquery - add values from one listbox to another, but do not include blank lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jQuery code that copies the selected values from one listbox to another:

```
$(adPerson + " option:selected").each(function(){  
    $(toNames).append($(this).clone());  
});
```

I'm trying to make sure no blank lines are added to the destination listbox, so I tried this:

```
$(adPerson + " option:selected").each(function(){  
       if($(this).text != "")
       {
    $(toNames).append($(this).clone()); 
       } 
});
```

The above code does not work - I think is is because of the way .each is used.

Any ideas?

Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to use `text()` instead of `text` if you wanted to test that way. It is a function, not a property.

However, all you need to is use the `:not(:empty)` jQuery selector:

```
$(adPerson + " option:selected:not(:empty)").each(function(){  
    $(toNames).append($(this).clone());  
});
```

You could further simplify it by using this:

```
$(toNames).append( $(adPerson + " option:selected:not(:empty)").clone() );
```

Comment: Thank you - that seems easy enough!

Derek